# How to get values from a table where its name I get from another table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this table:

MASTER_TABLE:

```
ID.        TABLE_NAME.        COLUMN_NAME:
-----------------------------------------
1.         tablename_1        name
2.         tablename_2.       age
```

And then:

TABLENAME_1

```
ID.     NAME.           AGE:
----------------------------
1.      XXXX            100
2.      YYYY.           200
```

Yeah, I know its weird. So what I need to do is to get let's say name and age from TABLENAME_1, but I don't know the table's name, and in order to get the name of the table, I just have an ID from MASTER_TABLE so by it I can get the table name, since for each field of the TABLENAME_1 there is one row in MASTER_TABLE from where I can get the name of the table and a name of a column

I know this should be pretty straightforward, but I am struggling with it and even with asking the right question on google

So I thought this could do it:

```
select name, age 
from 
    (select TABLE_NAME from MASTER_TABLE where id = 1) as table
```

But what I am getting it's just the name of the table.

Can someone please why this is not working and is breaking my SQL mental model? xD

Since what I understand is that with the subquery, I am giving to the FROM clause the name of the table and then the main SELECT can retrieve the actual name and age fields, since FROM points to the right table

Any explanation of why is this wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: You have to use dynamic SQL.  That is, you need to construct the SQL as a string by querying on the master table and then executing the string.  This is usually not a good database design.

Comment: Thanks! Could you please provide me with a working example so hopefully I understand why this does not work, and why a right approach would?

Comment: Also, I see all the time subqueries used for this kind of stuff, I am a bit frustrated TBH